# issues logging into oracle database 10g using command line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I forgot my username and password, and wanted to gain access to oracle database from the command line, below is what I've done so far:

```
sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect / as sysdba
SQL> desc dba_users
  error: ORA 04043 object dba_user does not exist

SQL> select username,password from dba_users;
  database not open: queries allowed on views/fixed tables only
```

Comment: `database not open:queries allowed on views/fixed tables only` You need to OPEN  the database first. `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`.

Comment: @ Lalit, I did that a moment ago, got the following error: ORA00600 internal error code

Comment: 1) connect / as sysdba only works if the user is in ORA_DBA windows group (if you use windows) or dba linux group (if you use linux -in this case check /etc/group because the linux oracle's dba group can be changed on install). You must check that the user who execute the commands is in this special OS group. And 2) you can change a forgotten password (with ALTER USER) but you cannot see a forgotten password (select username,password from dba_users;  will only return usernames and null in the password column).

Comment: @acesargl, thank you for the response. the codes suggested 'select username,password from dba_users' gave the same error I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is down :) 
Please do a startup first

Regards,